# How do I use two Directives with OR in Akka-HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I want to create a complex directive in Akka HTTP where I can use the query `/api/guitar?id=42` or the path `/api/guitar/42`. I did use two directives and it worked. However I would like to use everything in one directive where I can benefit from the `|` operator. So, I have this code:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route

object ComplexDirectives {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("ComplexDirectives")
    val complexRoute: Route = path("api" / "guitar") {
      (path("" / IntNumber) | parameter('id.as[Int])) { (itemNumber: Int) =>
        get {
          println(s"I found the guitar $itemNumber")
          complete(HttpEntity(
            ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
            s"""
               |<html>
               | <body>I found the guitar $itemNumber!</body>
               |</html>
               |""".stripMargin
          ))
        }
      }
    }
    println("http GET localhost:8080/api/guitar?id=43")
    println("http GET localhost:8080/api/guitar/42")
    Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8080).bindFlow(complexRoute)
  }
}
```

when I use a HTTP GET command `http GET localhost:8080/api/guitar?id=43` I get the guitar with id 43. But when I use the command `http GET localhost:8080/api/guitar/43` I cannot get the guitar. I also changed the directive to be only  `(path(IntNumber) | parameter('id.as[Int]))` but does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to concatenate paths. In order to do that you need to use `pathPrefix`. Try to do:

```
val complexRoute: Route = pathPrefix("api" / "guitar") {
  (path(IntNumber) | parameter('id.as[Int])) { (itemNumber: Int) =>
    get {
      println(s"I found the guitar $itemNumber")
      complete(HttpEntity(
        ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
        s"""
           |<html>
           | <body>I found the guitar $itemNumber!</body>
           |</html>
           |""".stripMargin
      ))
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that when declaring such path, more paths might be valid. For example, `http://localhost:8080/api/guitar/abc?id=43` is valid because it has a prefix of `api/guitar` and a parameter id.

If you want to block those paths, you need to use `pathEnd` or `pathEndOrSingleSlash` in the following way:

```
(path(IntNumber) | (pathEndOrSingleSlash & parameter('id.as[Int])))
```

which will support both `http://localhost:8080/api/guitar/?id=43` and `http://localhost:8080/api/guitar?id=43`

Or:

```
(path(IntNumber) | (pathEnd & parameter('id.as[Int])))
```

which will support only `http://localhost:8080/api/guitar?id=43`

Comment: humm, I didn't know that `pathPrefix` exists. thanks