# Unable to combine two directives using the | operator on Akka-Http

Tags: akka, akka-http

I want to extract a token either from the query parameter or the Authorization header.

For that, I created this directive:

```scala
(parameter("token".optional) | optionalHeaderValueByName("Authorization")).flatMap { _ match {
    case Some(token) =>
      // authenticate it
      complete(...)
    case None =>
      reject(AuthenticationFailedRejection)
  }
}
```

The issue is that requests with a "token" query parameter work, but requests that have the "Authorization" header (and no query parameter) don't. The `optionalHeaderValueByName` is skipped.

I *believe* it is because when `parameter("token".optional)` is rejected, it automatically returns a `401 Unauthorized` response.

If that is indeed the case, is there a way I can make it so it also checks the `optionalHeaderValueByName`?

I thought that the `|` operator was made for this.

Maybe it works when returning a route? And not when `flatMap`ping?

This post covers the same use-case: [How do I use two Directives with OR in Akka-HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65412329/how-do-i-use-two-directives-with-or-in-akka-http)

But for some reason, I can't replicate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe it is because when parameter("token".optional) is rejected, it automatically returns a 401 Unauthorized response.

I believe it's the opposite. You made "token" parameter optional, that means when it's absent it still will be accepted and the directive after `|` never evaluated. If you drop the `.optional` and `token` parameter is not there it will be rejected and directive after `|` will be evaluated.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thanks!